# Tabbed Content Using Alpine Js - First Visited Link

Tags: tailwind-css, alpine.js

The below code works with no issue.

When i click on tab1 etc... the links are getting selected.

But what i need is to highlight the tab which gets loaded at the very beginning

I have tried including utility classes such as `visited:border-indigo-500`

unfortunately those didn't work

```html
<div x-data="{ tab: '#tab1' }">

    <!-- Links here -->
    <div class="flex flex-row justify-start mx-4 space-x-4 text-white bg-indigo-300">
        <div>
            <div>
                <a class="px-4 border-b-2 border-gray-900 hover:border-green-400 focus:border-green-500 active:border-indigo-500 visited:border-indigo-500"
                href="#" x-on:click.prevent="tab='#tab1'">Tab1</a>

                <a class="px-4 border-b-2 border-gray-900 hover:border-green-400 focus:border-green-500 active:border-indigo-500 visited:border-indigo-500"
                href="#" x-on:click.prevent="tab='#tab2'">Tab2</a>

                <a class="px-4 border-b-2 border-gray-900 hover:border-green-400 focus:border-green-500 active:border-indigo-500 visited:border-indigo-500"
                href="#" x-on:click.prevent="tab='#tab3'">Tab3</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <!-- Tab Content here -->
    <div class="flex flex-row justify-start mx-4 space-x-4">
        <div>
            <div x-show="tab == '#tab1'" x-cloak>
            <p>This is the content of Tab 1</p>
        </div>

        <div x-show="tab == '#tab2'" x-cloak>
            <p>This is the content of Tab 2</p>
        </div>

        </div>
        <div x-show="tab == '#tab3'" x-cloak>
            <p>This is the content of Tab 3</p>
        </div>
    </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may manually focus the element inside [`x-init`](https://alpinejs.dev/directives/init) directive using [`x-ref`](https://alpinejs.dev/directives/ref). And you might want to add [`outline-none`](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/outline#remove-outlines) class to hide the default browser outline on the focused element.

```html
<link href="https://unpkg.com/tailwindcss@^2/dist/tailwind.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script defer src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/alpinejs/alpine@v2.x.x/dist/alpine.min.js"></script>

<div x-data="{ tab: '#tab1' }" x-init="$refs[tab].focus()">

    <!-- Links here -->
    <div class="flex flex-row justify-start mx-4 space-x-4 text-white bg-indigo-300">
        <div>
            <div>
                <a x-ref="#tab1" class="px-4 border-b-2 border-gray-900 outline-none hover:border-green-400 focus:border-green-500 active:border-indigo-500 visited:border-indigo-500"
                href="#" x-on:click.prevent="tab = '#tab1'">Tab1</a>

                <a x-ref="#tab2" class="px-4 border-b-2 border-gray-900 outline-none hover:border-green-400 focus:border-green-500 active:border-indigo-500 visited:border-indigo-500"
                href="#" x-on:click.prevent="tab = '#tab2'">Tab2</a>

                <a x-ref="#tab3" class="px-4 border-b-2 border-gray-900 outline-none hover:border-green-400 focus:border-green-500 active:border-indigo-500 visited:border-indigo-500"
                href="#" x-on:click.prevent="tab = '#tab3'">Tab3</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <!-- Tab Content here -->
    <div class="flex flex-row justify-start mx-4 space-x-4">
        <div>
            <div x-show="tab == '#tab1'" x-cloak>
            <p>This is the content of Tab 1</p>
        </div>

        <div x-show="tab == '#tab2'" x-cloak>
            <p>This is the content of Tab 2</p>
        </div>

        </div>
        <div x-show="tab == '#tab3'" x-cloak>
            <p>This is the content of Tab 3</p>
        </div>
    </div>

</div>
```

Comment: there is a small issue in this though, when you click somewhere else on the page, the selected menu goes away.

Comment: Because you only want to set the border on focus (`focus:border-green-500`). And border goes away when you click outside the element since it's not focused anymore.